# Blank output with mustache template, connect & node.js

Tags: node.js, mustache, node.js-connect

I'm just getting into this whole node.js business and like it so far; however I've run into an issue involving connect/mustach.

Here's the code for a simple one page app; at this point I'm really just trying to get the app to use my mustache templates so that I can take it from there.

```
var connect = require("connect"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    mustache = require("mustache");

connect(
  connect.static(__dirname + '/public'),
  connect.bodyParser(),
  function(req, res){
    var data = {
          variable: 'Some text that I'd like to see printed out. Should in the long run come from DB.'
        },
        htmlFile = fs.createReadStream(
          __dirname + "/views/index.html",
         { encoding: "utf8" }
        ),
        template = "",
        html;

    htmlFile.on("data", function(data){
      template += data;
    });
    htmlFile.on("end", function(){
      html = mustache.to_html(template, data);
    })

    res.end(html);
  }
).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

My problem here is that the above code generates a blank webpage.
If I log the `html`-variable I get two outputs of the html with the `variable` text attached in it, so the `to_html`-function seems to do it's job. And if I do `res.end('some string');` the string is displayed in the browser as it should.

The template is a plain old .html-file with a `<p>{{variable}}</p>`-tag in its body.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not using async code correctly. By the time `res.end(html)` gets called the file is not yet read. Correct usage:

```
 htmlFile.on("end", function(){
      html = mustache.to_html(template, data);
      res.end(html);
 })
```

Also you should take care of the syntax error: `variable: 'Some text that I'd like to see printed out. Should in the long run come from DB.'`
(misuse of ')

Comment: Ahhh there you have it; and of course, now that you mention it, it's clear as the day where the fault was. Thanks for pointing it out!